# Using Execvp to ls from argument

Tags: c, linux

I'm new to C and trying to understand why this code just return current directory file listing rather than the directory i pass to.

I used c11 standard gcc compiler

and just using ./a.out filedirectory
.....

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        char*args[3];
        if(argc > 1)
        {
                args[0] = "/bin/ls";
                args[1] = "-l";
                if(argv[2])
                {
                        args[2] = argv[2];
                        args[3] = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                        args[2] = NULL;
                }

                execvp(args[0],args);

                return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you *carefully* read the documentation of [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) and of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)? BTW, your question lacks a `Linux` or `Posix` tag since `execvp` is not defined in the C11 standard. Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: As usual, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger `gdb`** (so spend several hours learning it). You may also find [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) useful.

Comment: Side note: with `char *args[3]`, accessing `args[3]` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you Basile, I'll check the documentation of execvp again.

Answer (score 2):

You did not tell how are your running your program `myprog`. Let's suppose you run it as (for example) `./myprog /tmp/`.

In the [*C programming language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#cite_note-N1570-4) (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) array indexes start at 0!

Then when entering your `main` you have

- `argc` is 2
- `argv[0]` is the `"./myprog"` string
- `argv[1]` is the `"/tmp/"` string
- `argv[2]` is the `NULL` pointer (this is guaranteed by the C specification of `main` and implemented by [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)) since it is the `main` function

<sup>(In all other cases in C, arrays of pointers are *not* implicitly `NULL` terminated, but `main`'s `argv` is special)</sup>

Follow with a pencil or with the `gdb` debugger your program source. The first `if (argc > 0)` succeeds but the second one `if (argv[2])` fails. Then you have `args[0]` set to `"/bin/ls"`, `args[1]` set to `"-l"` and `args[2]` set to `NULL` before the `execvp` call.

See [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

You really should take the habit of compiling with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), e.g. compile `yoursource.c` source file into `myprog` executable with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -o myprog`) and learn how to **use the debugger `gdb`**.

BTW, your use of `args[3]` is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (out of bound indexing or [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)), so you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108), since `args` was declared as an array of dimension 3 (so valid indexes are only 0, 1 and 2). In your case a recent  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) would warn you.

Comment: There is also the strange bit of logic of the nested `if..else` inside of `if (argc > 0)` (which will always be true). Instead, a single `if (argc > 1) ... else ...` could accomplish what looks to be his goal.